# Error loading prophet library in R - How can I fix it?

Tags: r, macos, facebook-prophet

Can someone help me to solve the prophet library loading for Mac in R?
I have successfully installed the package, and when I try to load the library I get the following result:

```
> library(prophet) 
> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘prophet’
> in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  unable to load shared
> object
> '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/prophet/libs/prophet.so':
> dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/prophet/libs/prophet.so,
> 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libtbb.dylib   Referenced from:
> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/prophet/libs/prophet.so
> Reason: image not found
```

R version is R version 4.0.2, Built for Catalina

Answer (score 2):

try `library(rstan)` before `library(prophet)`

https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/464